# Looking for method / module to determine the compiler which was used for building the CPython interpreter

Tags: python, cmake

When I start the Python interpreter in command line mode I get a message saying which compiler was used for building it. Is there a way to get this information in Python ? I know I could start the interpreter with `subprocess.Popen` and parse the output, but I'm looking for an easier and more elegant method.

The background is that I want to build Python extensions for a CMake based C++ framework, and I would like to write a CMake macro wich checks if the correct compiler is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`platform.python_compiler()`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.python_compiler).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sys.version` variable to access this information:

```
>>> sys.version
'2.7.2 (default, Jun 29 2011, 11:17:09) \n[GCC 4.6.1]'
```

It will tell you which compiler was used to compile Python, but it won't ensure the mentioned compiler is installed on the system (this could be a pre-built Python version).